# How can I search for bounty questions?

Tags: feature-request, search, bounties

Is there any possible way to search and list the bountied questions separately in SE?

Comment: I would like to see a list of all [tag:perl] questions that have ever received a bounty. The answer is simple: **you can't.** Query would probably be too complex for SQL Server.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To list the current bounty questions, click on the [featured](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured) tab.

On the current UI (2019) it's at `https://stackoverflow.com/questions` (for example) where you'll see this:

[image]

There doesn't appear to be a way to limit the search though. There's no `hasbounty:` keyword on the [search page](https://stackoverflow.com/search). Since September 2011, the `hasnotice:1` search option can be used to show bounty posts, but that also [shows other posts with notices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111165/hasnotice1-includes-questions-that-no-longer-have-bounties) (deleted question).

Comment: This also works for sort/filtering a tag search! But not for normal searches.

Comment: `hasnotice` doesn't show questions with bounties at this time

Comment: Interestingly, I dont have any "featured" tab anywhere in my logged in stackexchange account UI.  However, following the link worked.  How odd that its really hard to find questions with bounty.  Not much point in adding bounty.

Comment: @JohnLittle yeah, in the 8 years since this answer was written the UI has changed quite a bit.

Answer (score 36):

Using combinations of advanced search operators, you can reach around 90%-95% accuracy:

1. `hasnotice:1` (bounty is considered a post notice, but there are more kinds of notices)
2. `closed:0` (show only questions which are not closed)
3. `locked:0` (exclude most common notice that isn't a bounty)
4. `lastactive:7d..` (questions active in the last 7 days, as bounty bumps the question)

Example for a full search term: **[`hasnotice:1 closed:0 locked:0 lastactive:7d..`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hasnotice%3A1%20closed%3A0%20locked%3A0%20lastactive%3A7d..)** - 438 results on Stack Overflow while there are 400 questions with bounties.)

Credits go to alexolut for [finding the fourth option](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54476/how-can-i-search-for-bounty-questions/200242?noredirect=1#comment954157_200242). :)

Comment: Really tricky way to search bounty questions.

Comment: Ha, I copy-pasted your query over and was about to change the date to today. I did a double take and had to look back over here to see if you were doing some sort of wizardry with the date, only to discover it's just a new answer to a three year old question. Apparently I completely missed the last sentence as well. Well done.

Comment: @Geobits lol! Blame hims056 for [pointing me here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200230/is-there-any-way-to-sort-bounty-questions?lq=1#comment637131_200230)! ;)

Comment: Will this advanced search work for other communities as well? e.g. Biology Can you show an example of how to use a particular tag in this search for past question which offered bounties?

Comment: @bonCodigo this is not possible for past bounties, I'm afraid, since only active bounties cause the question to have a post notice, which is the main part of my answer.

Comment: You can use relative dates, e.g. `lastactive:7d..1d`.

Comment: @alexolut awesome, almost perfect! Too bad it doesn't support 0d. (so questions asked since 12 AM won't appear.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard you could support my [request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293512/339911).

Comment: @alexolut already did. :)

Comment: For bounty question you can use 'lastactive:7d..' i.e. w/o '1d' at all.

Comment: I assume `closed:0` is a more efficient way to filter out a few more possibilities while replacing `is:q`.

Comment: @Nathan thanks, I was really n00b when writing that answer, I guess.... or short on coffee. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I would have put this as a comment on the answer from @Squatch but I have no rep on meta.stackexchange so I can't.  So here goes; maybe it's better as its own answer anyway.

I think Squatch's answer is in the right direction, but is not specified sufficiently precisely; people may have downvoted it because of that.  What you need to do is:

1. Go to the "Questions" section of stackoverflow by clicking the big orange "Questions" button near the top of the window
2. Then go to the "Featured" tab by clicking the tab; you will now see all questions with bounties, as far as I can tell (maybe "Featured" should be renamed to "Bounties"?)
3. Enter a search term in the search field at the very top right of the window, such as [java]; the previous list of questions with bounties will now be narrowed by that search term.  There is nothing magical about the brackets around the search term; brackets do not mean "with bounty".  (I think brackets just explicitly designate a tag, as opposed to other stuff you can type into the search field?)

If you enter a search term when you are not already on the "Featured" tab, you will not see only questions with bounties; you will then be doing your search in whatever other context you were in.

While I'm on that subject: The user interface for searching on SO is a bit odd, to me; since the search is apparently done within the current context (orange button and tab) being viewed, the search field should be positioned lower than those other user interface elements, not above them at the top right.  A search field at the top right, like SO's, is naturally assumed to do a context-free website-wide search.  It is also odd to me that "Unanswered" is in two places (as an orange button, and as a tab under "Questions"), and provides different things in those two places; that confuses me.  Those complaints are somewhat incidental to this question, but I think they have helped to create a general aura of confusion about how to search on SO; I know I found it to be a barrier initially.

Comment: This might work in the new navigation, which is not yet live for everyone, just those who chose to test it. For me, search results don't have any "featured" tab

Comment: Interesting.  I'm a total SO newbie; to the best of my knowledge I am not testing anything, but maybe I clicked through some beta-test offer that I didn't understand.  Anyhow, OK, maybe this answer only applies to that; thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Search for whatever you want using [the usual syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/search). And then

- add `?tab=Bounties` at the end of URL OR
- click on "Bountied" button at top of search results OR
- click "Filter" button on right and then check the "Has bounty" checkbox.

E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?tab=Bounties

[image]

Extras:

- You can sort by "Bounty ending soon".
- You can save a custom filter and it'll appear on your home page on RHS under "Custom filters".
  [image]