# How can I find questions that I have asked that currently have bounties on them?

Tags: support, search, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I search for bounty questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54476/how-can-i-search-for-bounty-questions)

How can I find questions that I have asked that currently have bounties on them?

Comment: I actually have no idea besides manually searching all your questions...

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54476/how-can-i-search-for-bounty-questions

Comment: You can narrow down to current questions by using "user:4653 hasaccepted:0" in the search field

Comment: Nitpick: OP wants to see only his own bountied questions, not all open bounties.  Voting to reopen.

Comment: [This feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29262/add-bounty-events-to-revision-history) would get most of the way there to finding what you asked for (since bounties only last 1 week). I've also voted to reopen (this question isn't a duplicate of the one I just linked to either, I was just pointing it out).