# Advanced search criteria for bounty questions?

Tags: feature-request, search, bountied-tab

All active questions with awarded bounty can be seen in the Featured tab. However, there seems to be way to make searches to the contents of any particular question tab.

I realize that this *is* pretty much a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54476/how-can-i-search-for-bounty-questions) but it has no clear answer whether there are any plans of supporting bounty searching or not.

So, could there possibly be a hasbounty:1 advanced search criteria?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think that this would be very useful -- I would like to search through the [currently 244](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured) questions to see if there are any bounties currently offered for questions tagged with [cuda](/questions/tagged/cuda).

Perhaps, slightly more in line with the other advanced super ninja search options, it would be more appropriate to use:

- `isfeatured:1`
- `isfeatured:0`

Or simply:

- `featured:1`
- `featured:0`

I think this would be a very useful extension with a minimal number of modifications required to the search engine.

**Note:** I realize that others are strongly opposed to the idea of search by *size of bounty* -- something which I am also against -- because of the perception that it would further encourage users to flock only to the largest bounties.

In contrast, I think the ability to search for the presence/absence of a bounty would be of great benefit as there are now so many questions with bounties on Stack Overflow -- a list which I'd really prefer not to have to pass through to find all of the C/C++/CUDA questions I feel I'd have a shot at answering correctly.

**Lastly:** I believe this functionality is already built-in to the server backend as clicking on the `featured` tab and then on a `Related` or `Favorite` tag will achieve the desired result (without the ability to perform more complex searches).  Hence, I'm hoping it wouldn't be too hard to implement.

Comment: Aw, I was just thinking today how useful this would be... makes me sad that two years later it hasn't been actioned upon (or even responded to)...

Answer (score 2):

**I realise this is MSE, but please let me point out the importance of this feature for StackOverflow specifically.**

While StackOverflow is ever growing, I find this feature is getting more and more necessary.

It has been a point of discussion on MSO before that question quality, in general, is dropping, see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252506/1313143) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late) for example and I'm sure there are similar discussions because the two I link to are highly upvoted.

Yesterday I was reading [a discussion on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171172/183189), where someone was venting his feelings about the fact that SO tends to reward low-quality quick answers more than high-quality detailed answers, and that he simply saw no reason anymore to invest a lot of time in writing detailed answers.

Someone said, in my opinion rightly so, that the problem lies in the fact that the front page is dominated by users who just want to give answers quickly to solve the simple problems that most askers have. It isn't a good place for those guys who *really* want to help out by giving as much detail as possible to an answer, and help solving complex questions that require more than 5 minutes of thought.

The place where these answerers want to be is the **featured** tab, and now the necessity of expanding this tab with such things as advanced search options becomes obvious. In my opinion, these ambitious answerers are the most important when it comes to SO's philosophy of building a library of knowledge that contains detailed answers and re-usable solutions to as much problems as possible.

**If we want to keep the good answerers, at least have the featured tab make some sense**. It begins with this very feature request, making it filterable and searchable as a seperate region of the site.