# Advanced search option to include questions with bounty among the search criteria and other cool search options

Tags: feature-request, search, bounties

I know this is similar to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68253/152951) which was also a duplicate of another question.  However, neither have been answered sufficiently so I am posting again hoping to get good answers or at least get the other question(s) noticed.  It also has additional criteria so I don't think it should be considered a duplicate.

What I think we are looking for are more search capabilities like as follows:

***answers:0 hasbounty:50 [cocos2d]***

(This would find questions with no answers that have a bounty of atleast 50 that are tagged cocos2d.)

Other cool types of search options could be:

***isfeatured*** (which would include questions listed in the featured tab in the search criteria)

***since:01/12/2010*** (would include questions posted since January 12 2010)

***before:06/12/2010*** (would include questions posted before June 12 2010)

***questionrep:1000*** (would include questions posted by users with atleast 1000 rep)

***answerrep:1000*** (would include questions with answers posted by users with atleast 1000 rep)

---Please post your cool search criteria ideas here too!