# Finding Featured Unanswered Posts

Tags: discussion, sorting

How to sort questions which are unanswered **AND** featured?

If you want to display *unanswered* you can type

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=unanswered
```

and

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured
```

for *featured* questions.

I've tried to mix them both but it doesn't work at all...

Comment: I don't think multiple sorting is implemented at all. There is a tab for each sort criterium, and a 1-1 mapping between the sort criteria and the tabs. There are no "composite" tabs (yet).

Comment: I would rather like to see unanswered tab simply ordered by *date*. The current random order makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: @YourCommonSense it's not random, it is sorted by descending score, then by ascending # of answers.  Not the best method I agree, but not quite random

Comment: @psubsee2003 errr. number of *answers* for *unaswered* questions?

Comment: @YourCommonSense yes.  SO posts with unaccepted/unupvoted answers as unanswered.

Comment: @psubsee2003 ugh. I see now. Well, it is order by votes, practically. Well, no matter how you call it or what was the intention, but as an *actual* result I never browse to this tab at all.

Comment: I've added some better filtering based on a [recent answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200242/182513) to a different question that helps improve the accuracy of the search.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a perfect solution, but you can use the [SO search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching), rather than combining the unanswered and featured tab to get part of the way there.

The reason it is not a perfect solution is there is no `hasbounty` operator in the advanced search, but there is a `hasnotice`, where the notice would be any notice, including the bounty notice.

[`answers:0 hasnotice:1 locked:0 is:question lastactive:2013-10-05..2013-10-12`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A0+hasnotice%3A1+locked%3A0+is%3Aquestion+lastactive%3A2013-10-05..2013-10-12)

1. `answers:0` (filter on questions that do not have any answers)<sup>1</sup>
2. `hasnotice:1` (bounty is considered a post notice, but there are more kinds of notices)
3. `is:question` (show only questions, we don't want stuff like locked answers)
4. `locked:0` (exclude most common notice that isn't a bounty)
5. `lastactive:[week ago date]..[today]` (format yyyy-mm-dd to exclude questions with notice like "Insufficient explanation" and others)

My original query (`answers:0 hasnotice:1`) returns 112 posts, but the amended one from [Sha Wiz Dow Ard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/152859/sha-wiz-dow-ard), who identified some some more [advanced search criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200242/182513) to help filter on Featured Questions more accurately, trims this list down to 104 posts.

A major disadvantage is that the system classifies posts with unupvoted answers (with none being accepted) as unanswered as well, and this will not return these.  Searching for posts by answer score is not implemented, but you can do another search with `isaccepted:0` instead of `answers:0` to find these, but they will be any unaccepted post, not just those without upvotes.

There is a feature request, [Advanced search criteria for bounty questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68253/182513), to add `isfeatured` to the search operators so you don't need so many operators to filter on bounty questions.  So you can show your support for that post, but it still won't correct the limitation with unaccepted 0-score posts.

Comment: But remember Unanswered tab shows questions with no answers or *no upvoted answers*

Comment: @Him yes, i added that limitation in my recent edit

Comment: Ahh I see. Out of the internet for few moments, so no ajax edit notification. :)

Comment: [There is a feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68253/187824) regarding searching bounty questions

Comment: @hims056 thanks, I was actually looking for that.  No idea why I couldn't find it.

Comment: [Here you go...](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfeature-request%5D+search+bounty+questions)

Comment: @hims056 Ugh, sometimes the simplest queries work best :-)  I got too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I now use to show post with bounty in my tags :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%20libcurl