# add an hasBounty:bool in search tool

Tags: feature-request, bounties, search

Currently, there is no way to do advanced search with bounties ([Finding Featured Unanswered Posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198397/finding-featured-unanswered-posts) is not satisfying me).

Is there a way to ask this option to be enabled with the same behavior than the others :

- isaccepted: yes/true/1 returns only answers that have been marked "accepted"; no/false/0 returns only answers that are not marked accepted.
- hascode: yes/true/1 returns only posts that contain code blocks; no/false/0 returns only posts that contain no code.
- hasaccepted: yes/true/1 returns only questions that have accepted answers; no/false/0 returns only questions with no accepted answers.
- closed: yes/true/1 returns only questions that are closed; no/false/0 excludes closed questions from the search.
- duplicate: yes/true/1 returns questions that have been marked as a duplicate of another question; no/false/0 excludes duplicate questions from the search.
- migrated: yes/true/1 returns only questions that have been migrated to a different site; no/false/0 excludes migrated questions from the search.
- locked: yes/true/1 returns only locked posts (which have edits, votes, comments, and new answers disabled); no/false/0 returns only posts that are not locked.
- hasnotice: yes/true/1 returns only posts with a notice shown below them; no/false/0 returns only posts that do not have a notice applied.
- wiki: yes/true/1 returns only community wiki posts; no/false/0 returns only non-community wiki posts.

---

- hasbounty: yes/true/1 returns only active bounty posts; no/false/0 returns only non active bounty posts.

Comment: Should be `hasbounty:`, no?

Comment: @AaronBertrand toootally right. Forgive my poor English ;)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220340/syntax-to-search-for-bounty-questions

Comment: @random sorry for dup. Should I delete my post ?

Comment: Depends. Do you think it will help lead to the other question?

Comment: @random no clue. I hope