# Syntax to search for bounty questions

Tags: feature-request, search

There is a manual here https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/stack-overflow-search-now-61-less-crappy/ on the advanced SO search operators.

It would be nice to have a `bounty` operator, which works as follows:

```
[bounty:150] [c++]
```

Finds all the questions tagged `c++` with an open bounty of 150 or higher.

Comment: Seems legit, upped

Comment: Is that open bounty? Because if search for [c++] and then click the featured tab you see the 15 questions that curently have a bounty. It doesn't take too much time to scan them for the 150's.

Comment: The point is to do a quick search for any question with a specific bounty. Regardless of tags.

Comment: Related: [How can I search for bounty questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54476/309922) and [Advanced search criteria for bounty questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68253/advanced-search-criteria-for-bounty-questions)