# List previously featured questions

Tags: feature-request, bounties, bountied-tab

Questions which currently have bounties are visible on `/questions?sort=featured`, but [there's no `hasbounty:1` or `featured:1` search keyword](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54476/how-can-i-search-for-bounty-questions) on the [search page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=) to find questions which have previously been featured but are not featured anymore.

There's [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/electronics/q/114556/answers-awarded-bounties):

```sql
-- Answers awarded bounties 
-- Shows answers that have been awarded bounties, most recent answers first.

SELECT post.Id AS [Post Link], 
       vote.BountyAmount AS Bounty,
       post.CreationDate AS Date
FROM Posts post
     JOIN Votes vote ON vote.PostId = post.Id
     JOIN Posts parent ON post.ParentId = parent.Id
WHERE     
      vote.VoteTypeId = 9  AND
      vote.BountyAmount <> 0             
ORDER BY post.CreationDate DESC​
```

which lists all the answers that have been awarded bounties, but that doesn't include questions that might be as old as 3 months, and doesn't give a good preview.

Can the featured tab include history, or a `hasbounty:1` search keyword be added?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the advanced search option should be `hadbounty:1`?

Comment: I was trying to keep some modicum of consistency with the other search options.  That would add yet another tense.  However, that's probably the least important component of this feature request: Is it useful?  Is it important?  Is it possible?  are all more important questions.