# Show only questions with a bounty and without an accepted answer?

Tags: support, bounties, search

Some sites have many questions with bounties on them. I'd rather not go through the ones that already have an accepted answer. Is there a way to sort questions to see only the ones that have a bounty and *no accepted* answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply use search for that. Search for bountied questions by searching for [unlocked posts with a notice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54476/how-can-i-search-for-bounty-questions), adding `hasaccepted:no` to the search:

> [`is:q hasaccepted:0 hasnotice:1 locked:0`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20hasaccepted%3a0%20hasnotice%3a1%20locked%3a0)

The search results include a few protected posts (link [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow-how-we-can-speed-up-the-android-emulator)) but the majority of these are bountied questions.

Also see the [advanced search help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching).