# How to find past questions within a particular tag that offered a bounty?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, bounties

I have seen [this post which is about finding active/featured questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54476/201662) with bounties. But what I want to find out is **past** questions within a particular tag that already offered a bounty. Is it possible? If so how to go about it?

I intend to use it for both meta, full and beta sites. As of now I don't see featured tab within questions in the beta sites.

Comment: Good question - perhaps write a [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries) query, unless one is already written. could be a modified version of the [Past bounties by bounty date](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/261072/past-bounties-by-bounty-date) query

Comment: what you mean by "particular tag"? language tag (ruby) or "suggest tags" (e.g. bounty)

Comment: @HackerKarma for e.g. either language *(VBA, SQL)* or *(array, group by)* for SO. But I intend to run it in other communities as well.

Comment: @bonCodigo I'm currently participated in the [new-nav: Improving our navigation, the next iteration](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261307/improving-our-navigation-the-next-iteration) and I don't see anything like what you suggested. I will with santiago suggested route. +1 for your post.

Comment: @HackerKarma That's great. I was trying to look for a past question that I thought was in my *favourites* in one community. But it wasn't and then the search wasn't successful at all.

Comment: I'd be very interested in a SEDE query about this (don't quite have the abilities to write one yet)

Comment: @santiago I am not sure if the SEDE works for a beta like Biology. I am trying out SEDE for SO and Chemistry.SE.

Comment: Biology has graduated - no longer in beta. I would be interested to see what you come up with!

Comment: @santiago Oh well! Now I wonder if *featured* tab only appears when there are unaccepted questions with bounties...Because as of now, I don't see featured tab in Biology.SE

Comment: Does this work for you: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/342055/past-questions-with-offered-bounty-with-specific-tag? I just made it... @bonCodigo

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ I had found the question I wanted. And I was looking for this `Votes.VoteTypeId         = 8  `, yes it seems to work, the last result out of 20 are the one I was looking for. Further refining may be needed. But it works. How about adding multiple tags?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a stab at making a query with SEDE.

See it [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/342075/past-questions-with-specific-tag-that-have-had-a-bounty-on-them-with-date-range).

It uses a bit of SQL from other queries on the site to do it.

Note that SEDE updates weekly so you will only find bounties at least a week old.

```
SELECT top 50 Posts.Id as [Post Link]
FROM Posts
    INNER JOIN Votes             ON Posts.Id       = Votes.PostId
    INNER JOIN PostTags          ON Posts.Id       = PostTags.PostId
    INNER JOIN Tags              ON PostTags.TagId = Tags.id
WHERE Votes.VoteTypeId         = 8       
    AND Tags.TagName   = '##TagName##'
    AND Posts.CreationDate > '##AfterDate##'
    AND Posts.CreationDate < '##ToDate##'
```

Comment: If you can add a date range, that would be great, but this is already good enough for the job I was intending to ;) Just *beautified* your answer with the code snippet.

Comment: @bonCodigo shouldn't be too hard - lemme see

Comment: @bonCodigo hmmm I can add a date range for the actual *post*, but unfortunately I don't know how to (no idea if it's even possible) add a date range for the bounty *start date* - is that OK? I've updated it - see the new  link.

Comment: Very nice work @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ!