# Zero value in relative dates in search

Tags: feature-request, search

Using SE search engine you can find posts active on relative dates. E.g.:

- posts active yesterday: [`lastactive:1d`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=lastactive%3A1d)
- posts active from yesterday to most recent: [`lastactive:1d..`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=lastactive%3A1d..)

But search criteria like [`lastactive:1d..0d`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=lastactive%3A1d..0d) is not recognized.

My request is to recognize relative dates with zero at the end (`Nd..0d`) same as `Nd..`.

More over for search posts active on today you could use [`lastactive:0d`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=lastactive%3A0d). Currently to search for today posts you need to specify absolute date only.

Comment: To view active posts from yesterday and today, can't you just look through the active list, and browse until you get to one that is too old? Why do you want to do complex searching to achieve that end?

Comment: @HarryVervet because I don't see any reason to forbid such search via search page.

Comment: Given there are so many good alternatives to this (you've mentioned two in your post), all I'll add is that last active in 0 days doesn't mean anything. 0 posts are active in 0 days.